# C++ - Limit the string length

Tags: c++

I want to create a program that allows the user to create a password and username. However, the password must be between 6 and 10 characters. How would I limit the character input? Also, what if I want the password to include capital letters?

Here's a look at the program so far to give you an idea of what I am trying to do (NOTE: I know the program itself is obviously unfinished but I just want to give you a visual):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "          Welcome to the ECE!! Password Proram!\n";
    std::cout << "Username rules: must be 5-10 characters long with no space\n";
    std::cout << "Password rules: must be 6+ characters long\n";
    std::cout << "Must contain one uppercase letter and one number but no space\n";
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------\n";

    //Let's get our password!
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    const int

    //use a do while loop for input validation
    do {    
        std::cout << "Enter your username: ";
        std::cin >> username;                       //add input validation               
    } while ();

    std::cout << "Enter your password:";
    std::cin >> password;    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To limit character input, you would want to check if the input length is between 6 and 10 characters inclusive. (I don't know of a way to cut off input after 10 characters) You would do something like

```
start: // A label to direct where the program should go when goto is called.
while(password.length() > 10 || password.length() < 5)
{
    std::cout << "The password must be between 5 and 10 characters inclusive." << endl;
    std::cin >> password;
}
// To check if there is a capital letter
bool foundUpperLetter = false;
for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)
{
    if(foundUpperLetter == true)
        break;
    if('A' <= password[i] && password[i] <= 'Z')
        foundUpperLetter = true;
}
if(!foundUpperLetter)
{
    std::cout << "You did not include an uppercase letter in your input. Please try again." << endl;
    goto start; // Will make the program go back to label start.
}
```

You could also add more code to the above section to check for other attributes that the password requires.

Source: 15 months of coding for school and personal enjoyment. Please add your own answer if there is a better way to do something or if you know a way to cut off input after 10 characters

Comment: Is there another way to check for uppercase letters? The way you did, it's giving my compiler some errors (I'm using a mac)

Comment: @HassanKamara I accidentally left something out, I fixed it

Comment: I am having trouble integrating those two conditions (the first being checking to make sure it's between 5-10 characters and then also checking to see if it has a capital letter in it. My idea is to print separate error messages when either of those conditions are violated but the way I have it right now, it is printing both error messages (one saying the password is less than 6 characters and that it doesn't have  capital letter)

Comment: You could make them re-enter a password until it is between 5 and 10 characters, then when they do that, then move on to the next part (the uppercase check). If it is satisfied, then move on. Otherwise, use a goto statement to loop back to the re-entering stage. You could use this goto for each validation check. Fixed this above. @HassanKamara

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using std::string, you can use password.size() after getting the user input and checking if the size is within the limits of 5 & 10. If it's not, simply re-query the user for another password. This would be best done in a while loop. 
Here is an example of some code from a higher level:

```
do{
    std::cout << "Enter your password:";
    std::cin >> password;
}while (password.size() < 6 || password.size() > 10)
```

You're already doing a similar thing with username, so I was a bit confused on if you meant to be asking about password or not.

Answer (score -1):

On a conceptual level: you could take in a string input, check the length and other properties (i.e. contains one uppercase letter), use it for further operations. If it does not meet the following criteria, ask the user to re-enter the information.